# How to use the residual energy values inside the TCL script using NS2?

Tags: cluster-analysis, cluster-computing, k-means, hierarchical-clustering, ns2

I am working on k-means algorithm and I need to elect CHs duo to the residual energy values. Is there such a way to extract the residual energy values while executing the TCL script, and simultaneously use these values while running the TCL script? So that I can use the extracted values to elect the CHs.

I know that if I create an energy model then the residual energy will be print in the `trace file`, but I am looking for a way to use these values `before print them out in the trace file`

Comment: I think of applying the energy model manually in my script and get the residual energy values and stored them in some variable to get advantages of them. or to stop the running of the program and read the trace file to get the residual energy values and then continue running. Is there such a code to apply one of the two ideas?

Comment: Google, define network residual energy : "A node looses a particular amount of energy for every packet transmitted and every packet received. As a result, the value of initialEnergy_ in a node gets decreased. The current value of energy in a node after receiving or transmitting routing packets is the residual energy."